# SetEnvIf - set variable based on another variable

Tags: apache, setenvif

So I'm trying to emulate AND with SetEnvIf to block/allow httpd access based on country and city. This is my block in my httpd conf:

```
SetEnvIf RemoteHost "^" AllowEntry=0
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowEntry=1
SetEnvIf GEOIP_REGION MA AllowEntry=AllowEntry+1


SetEnvIf AllowEntry 2 AllowEntry2
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowEntry2
```

But it doesn't work, line 3 will assign the value "AllowEntry+1" to the variable AllowEntry instead of 2.

It doesn't need to be 2 as in the math operation, the string "1+1" would work as well.

Any ideas? Is it possible?

PS: would still like to know if it's possible but for now I solve my requirement with:

SetEnvIfExpr "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} == 'US' && %{ENV:GEOIP_REGION} == 'MA'"  AllowEntry